# How to get more supplies once FOBs run out?

Tags: wargame-ee

In Wargame: European Escalation, is there a way to get more supplies once your Forward Operating Bases (FOBs) run out? Can you build more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't build more. The only thing you can do is to conquer bases from your enemy or capture their support vehicles.

You can do that by moving your units to the FOB or Supply Truck / Helicopter and clearing out enemy units around it. Or simply have more units there than your enemy.

Then the base are belong to you.

If you have support vehicles left in your command menu and your FOB runs out, bring them on the battlefield since they arrive fully loaded.